# C++ Why is my comparison between int and str.length() not working?

Tags: c++, string-length

I am sending an array of names to a function that should compute length of each name and send back the largest one as number of characters.  My comparison between longest and names[i].length() is never true.  I initialize longest to -1 so first name should replace -1 with the length of characters in that name, however at the end of the function it return longest with my initial value of -1

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int findLongestName(string names[], int numNames);

int main() {
   string names[25] {"Bob Hope", "Steve Nice", "Mary Jane", "James Higgenbothem", "Ace Blue"};
   int numNames = 5;
   int longName;

   longName = findLongestName(names, numNames);
   cout << "Longest name is " << longName << " characters.\n";

   system("PAUSE");
   return 0;
}

int findLongestName(string names[], int numNames) {
    int longest = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < numNames; i++) {
        if (names[i].length() > longest) {
            longest = names[i].length();
        }
    }

    return longest;
}
```

Can someone take a look and explain what I am doing wrong?  I should/want to receive 18 back from the function for name James Higgenbothem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is with the data type `names[i].length()` returns an `unsigned int`. Comparing `-1` with `names[i].length()` will always give you a `false`.

```
int findLongestName(string names[], int numNames) {
    unsigned int longest = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numNames; i++) {
        if (names[i].length() > longest) {
            longest = names[i].length();
        }
    }

    return longest;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

when comparing a signed value `longest` with unsigned value `names[i].length()`, the compiler converts the signed value into an `unsigned` value, which makes `int longest` which is initially `-1`, a very big unsigned number `4294967295`

So, essentially, this always evaluates to false:

```
if (names[i].length() > longest)
```

Fixes:

You can typecast the unsigned int returned from *string.length()* into int

```
if ((int)names[i].length() > longest) {
```

or make *longest* an unsigned int from the start